# How to get working days list in a week in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, week-number, weekday

I've developed **google sheets** to trace targets & achievements of sales forces. There is a sheet name **dump** where I upload sales data, which contains a **date** column[A], an **SR ID** column[C], sales **quantity** column[N]. There is another sheet name **sales analysis** where I calculate ADS, STD, RADS, etc. **Now I need to get weekly sales from dump sheets to check either individual sales officers complete their weekly target or not.**

**Column heading shall be like**: Week 1 Week 2 Week 3 Week 4

**Possible formula in Week1 Column:** *sum(filter(dump!$N$2:N, dump!$C$2:C=[SRID], dump!$A$2:A=[formula to check either the date is in the week 1 of current month or not]))*

**Possible formula in Week2 Column:** *sum(filter(dump!$N$2:N, dump!$C$2:C=[SRID], dump!$A$2:A=[formula to check either the date is in the week 2 of current month or not]))*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function with `pivot` clause.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.